# .NET 4.0 Full include Client Profile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, distribution

I started out sending my app out with 4.0 Client Profile, but now I need the Full 4.0 framework because I need some ASP.NET "stuff" with my new app.

On a new PC that does not have 4.0-anything on it, can I install the "Full" 4.0 framework and have my "Client Profile" 4.0 framework code still work?

Or do I have to have the end-user install both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The full framework should be a superset that includes everything from the Client Profile.

Comment: Indeed, thank you.  To clarify, if I have a compiled Client Profile app using log4net that needs Client Profile, installing the full 4.0 framework places both the Full and CP on the PC so that it all works.  Confirmed.  Thanks again -

Answer (score 1):

Full includes everything in the client profile.